# how to on-demand revalidate all the pages at once

Tags: node.js, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to revalidate all the pages of my website on a certain event,

the problem that I'm running through is that I have to do it page by page :

```js
...
try {
 await res.unstable_revalidate(
  `/`
 );
 await res.unstable_revalidate(
  `/about`
 ;
 await res.unstable_revalidate(
  `/shop`
 );
 ...
 return res.json({ revalidated: true });
} catch (err) {
   return res.status(500).send('Error revalidating');
  }
```

So my question is: Is there a way to on-demand ( using unstable_revalidate() ) revalidate all the pages of my website, Or do I have to do it page by page ?

Comment: If you are using SSG and you want to revalidate all the pages of the website, could you trigger a rebuild of your site to achieve the same effect?

Comment: I don't know, this is what I'm Asking?

Comment: My assumption is that all your pages are statically generated when a build is triggered for your site. Exact steps will depend on your CI/CD and hosting setup but several providers have webhooks you can call to trigger a site rebuild and deployment. My suggestion was to do that instead of invalidating individual pages

Comment: @ChristianHagelid I'm looking to do the same thing. Is triggering a new build the only way?

Answer (score 2):

Next.js currently has no built-in way to revalidate all pages at once. I have created a method that returns all static (e.g. index.js) and dynamic (e.g. [slug].js) pages, which looks like that:

```js
export const getAllPages = async (): Promise<string[]> => {
    const pages: PageInfo[] = [
        "/",
        "/about",
        "/shop"
    ];
    (await getProductUrls()).forEach(url=> pages.push(url));

    return pages;
}
```

In my case, I need this function anyways for a dynamic sitemap.xml. `getProductUrls` could return the dynamic page URLs for your product pages e.g.
The revalidation api route looks like that:

```js
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    if (!req.query.secret || req.query.secret !== "SOME_SECRET_FOR_AUTORIZATION" || req.method !== "POST") {
        return res.status(401).end("Not Authorized");
    }

    try {
        const pages = await getAllPages();
        const prefixedPages = pages.map(p => p.startsWith("/") ? p : "/" + p);
        const suffixedPages = prefixedPages.map(p => p.endsWith("/") ? p : p + "/");
        await Promise.all(suffixedPages.map(async (page) => {
            try {
                await res.revalidate(page);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        }));
        return res.status(200).end("Revalidated");
    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(500).end("Error");
    }
}
```

As next.js requires all URLs with a trailing and a leading slash for revalidation, these are added as the first step if not present yet.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

this should work with next.js 13. this is how you set tags when fetching in next.js 13. assume those are in different pages

```
const res1= await fetch(url1,{next:{tags:"about"}})
const res2= await fetch(url2,{next:{tags:"shop"}})
```

you set a route handler, let's say at `api/revalidate/route.js`. you should be sending tags by query params like this

```
http://localhost:3000/api/revalidate?tag1=about&tag2=shop&secret=12132
```

on-demand validation is set for admins. so admins should prevent other users from invalidating. that is why you should be implementing secret key

```
import {revalidateTag} from "next/cache"

export async function POST(request){
    const tag1= request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("tag1")
    const tag2= request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("tag2")
    const secret= request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("secret")

    if(secret!==process.env.SECRET){
        return Response.json({message:"INvalid admin secret",{status:401}})
    }
    // I am not sure if revalidateTag accepts array
    revalidateTag(tag1)
    revalidateTag(tag2)
    .....
    return Response.json({revalidatedAll:true})
}
```

similarly you can use `path revalidation`. the only difference is url will change:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/revalidate?path0=/&path1=about&path2=shop&secret=12132
```

and instead of `revalidateTag`, you use

```
 import {revalidatePath} from "next/cache"
```